# Does batch normalization bias the gradient?

Tags: deep-learning, bias, gradient-descent, unbiased-estimator

With a training set of size $N$, let $L_i(\theta)$ denote the loss of the $i^\text{th}$ training example when the model has parameters $\theta$. Then the training loss $L(\theta)$ is equal to the mean of all the $L_i(\theta)$:
$$ L(\theta) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N L_i(\theta) \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\partial L_i}{\partial \theta}$$

In conventional stochastic gradient descent (SGD), a batch $\mathcal{B}$ is randomly sampled from the entire training set, and the quantities
$$L_{\mathcal{B}} = \frac{1}{\lvert\mathcal{B}\rvert} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{B}} L_i(\theta) \\
\frac{\partial L_{\mathcal{B}}}{\partial \theta} = \frac{1}{\mathcal{B}}\sum_{i \in \mathcal{B}} \frac{\partial L_i}{\partial \theta}$$
are clearly unbiased<sup>1</sup> estimators for the training loss and its gradient, respectively. So it's quite reasonable to use $\partial L_{\mathcal B} / \partial \theta$ as a substitute for $\partial L / \partial \theta$ in gradient descent.

In [batch normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf), the training loss $L_i$ for an individual example is no longer defined -- instead, batch statistics are used in the computation of $L_{\mathcal{B}}$, so that the "loss" of each example in $\mathcal{B}$ depends on all the other examples. Thus the trivial argument above that $\partial L_{\mathcal{B}} / \partial \theta$ is unbiased fails.

- Does anybody care whether the gradient estimator is biased in an SGD variation like batch normalization?
- Am I right in my belief that the estimator is, in fact, biased? (In other words, that the expected value of $\partial L_{\mathcal B}/\partial \theta$ for fixed $\theta$ depends on the batch size)

<sup>1</sup> Assuming $\mathcal{B}$ is sampled randomly with replacement. Other sampling techniques are often used in practice.